# PH=PSPACE implies collapse of PH?

Tags: complexity-theory

If PH=PSPACE, does this imply that the PH collapses to one of its levels?

(somehow I get an error message when posting "question doesn't meet quality standard" so I add this sentence in order to workaround it)

Comment: Rather than adding spurious text to meet the quality standards, you should add actual content. What research did you do to try to find the answer. Why do you think that PH=PSPACE might cause a collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it says so on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy

"If the polynomial hierarchy has any complete problems, then it has only finitely many distinct levels. Since there are PSPACE-complete problems, we know that if PSPACE = PH, then the polynomial hierarchy must collapse"